# How to use cross reference in the title of the appendix in this template?

Tags: cross-referencing

The template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-michigan-dissertation-template-unofficial/tpnjzndnrzmf

I tried to change the first line of example_appendix_01.tex to

```
\chapter{Appendix for~\ref{chpt:introduction}}
```

then got errors. "chpt:introduction" is the label for example_chapter_01.tex.

I was wondering how to fix this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this recipe:

(1) Delete the `.out` file created by LaTeX in a previous failed compilation. (Or make (2) to (4) and re run LaTeX twice)

(2) Add `\usepackage{refcount}` to the `packages.tex` file.

(3) Have `\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapter:introduction}`

(4) Use `\chapter{Appendix for chapter \getrefnumber{chapter:introduction}}\label{chapter:appendix_01}`
(==>  Remove the symbol `~`)

The package `refcount`  converts  references to numbers with the command  `\getrefnumber`

[image: b]

The problem is related to the `thesis-umich` class as this simple example shows:

```
%%\documentclass{book} % Works

\documentclass{thesis-umich} % Fail <<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Introduction}\label{chpt:introduction}
    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendix for chapter~\ref{chpt:introduction}}\label{chpt:appendix_01}      
\end{document}
```